# Should this be $(bx-a)^2=2$ instead of $x^2=2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

In the [Wikipedia article on Field extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_extension), it says "$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2) = \{a+b\sqrt 2 : a,b\in \mathbb Q\}$ is the smallest extension of $\mathbb Q$ containing all solutions to $x^2=2$."

Should this be $(bx-a)^2=2$ instead of $x^2=2$?
I mean that this $(bx-a)^2=2$ consists of set $Q(\sqrt{2})$, which is smallest extension field of field $Q$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2)$ is not dependent on any parameters.

You're missing the point of $a,b$ in the statement that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2) = \{a+b\sqrt 2 : a,b\in \mathbb Q\}$.

You need to have the real solutions of $x^2=2$ which are $\pm \sqrt 2$. Then you need to be closed under the field operations originally defined for $\mathbb Q$. This gives you arbitrary things $a+b\sqrt 2$ which should lie in the set, for any rational $a,b$.